# Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'BigInt' of 'data' with web3 dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ethereum, web3dart

I am trying to sign a transanction off chain but it's giving me that error.

```
var data = contract.function('permit').encodeCall([
      credentialsA.address,
      appOwnerCredentials.address,
      1000,

      deadline,
      0,
      Uint8List(32),
      Uint8List(32),
    ]);
```

the code above is what is generating the error below

```
E/flutter ( 6175): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'BigInt' of 'data'
E/flutter ( 6175): #0      UintType.encode (package:web3dart/src/contracts/abi/integers.dart)
E/flutter ( 6175): #1      TupleType.encode (package:web3dart/src/contracts/abi/tuple.dart:71:14)
E/flutter ( 6175): #2      ContractFunction.encodeCall (package:web3dart/src/contracts/abi/abi.dart:267:10)
E/flutter ( 6175): #3      Contract.transferDymeFrom (package:dymer2/models/contract.dart:1161:41)
E/flutter ( 6175): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6175):
```

I am trying to use the "permit" function in erc20 token

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the 'data' variable anywhere?

Comment: naa, just that one, I even changed the variable name to something different. it still give the same error with that name "data". So I don't think it's something about the variable name.

Comment: https://github.com/simolus3/web3dart/issues/118  go through the link above; it might give you some ideas.